# Error loading caveman framework on slime

Tags: common-lisp, quicklisp, cl

starting on lisp for a college project, and wanted to use the caveman framework. However, on trying to load it using

(ql:quickload :caveman)

In emacs/quicklisp/slime/sbcl on Ubuntu 14, I get a

```
Error while trying to load definition for system static-vectors
from pathname
/home/kite/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/static-vectors-1.6/static-vectors.asd:

   COMPILE-FILE-ERROR while compiling
   #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "cffi-toolchain" "toolchain" "asdf-compat">
   [Condition of type ASDF/FIND-SYSTEM:LOAD-SYSTEM-DEFINITION-ERROR]
```

as requested, the backtrace ...

```
  0: ((FLET #:HANDLER1599 :IN ASDF/FIND-SYSTEM:LOAD-ASD) #<UIOP/LISP-BUILD:COMPILE-FILE-ERROR {CA17CE9}>)
  1: (SIGNAL #<UIOP/LISP-BUILD:COMPILE-FILE-ERROR {CA17CE9}>)
  2: (ERROR UIOP/LISP-BUILD:COMPILE-FILE-ERROR :CONTEXT-FORMAT "~/asdf-action::format-action/" :CONTEXT-ARGUMENTS ((#<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:COMPILE-OP > . #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "cffi-toolchain" "too..
  3: (UIOP/LISP-BUILD:CHECK-LISP-COMPILE-RESULTS NIL T T "~/asdf-action::format-action/" ((#<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:COMPILE-OP > . #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "cffi-toolchain" "toolchain" "asdf-compat">)))
  4: ((SB-PCL::EMF ASDF/ACTION:PERFORM) #<unavailable argument> #<unavailable argument> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:COMPILE-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "cffi-toolchain" "toolchain" "asdf-compat">)
  5: ((:METHOD ASDF/ACTION:PERFORM-WITH-RESTARTS :AROUND (T T)) #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:COMPILE-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "cffi-toolchain" "toolchain" "asdf-compat">) [fast-method]
  6: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:PERFORM-PLAN (LIST)) ((#1=#<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > . #2=#<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "uiop">) (#3=#<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:COMPILE-OP > . #2#) (#<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > . #2#) (#1# . ..
  7: ((FLET SB-C::WITH-IT :IN SB-C::%WITH-COMPILATION-UNIT))
  8: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:PERFORM-PLAN :AROUND (T)) ((#1=#<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > . #2=#<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "uiop">) (#3=#<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:COMPILE-OP > . #2#) (#<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > . #2#) (#..
  9: ((FLET SB-C::WITH-IT :IN SB-C::%WITH-COMPILATION-UNIT))
 10: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:PERFORM-PLAN :AROUND (T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {BE724D1}>) [fast-method]
 11: ((:METHOD ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE (ASDF/OPERATION:OPERATION ASDF/COMPONENT:COMPONENT)) #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "cffi-grovel">) [fast-method]
 12: ((SB-PCL::EMF ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE) #<unused argument> #<unused argument> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "cffi-grovel">)
 13: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE))
 14: ((:METHOD ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE :AROUND (T T)) #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "cffi-grovel">) [fast-method]
 15: ((SB-PCL::EMF ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE) #<unused argument> #<unused argument> ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "cffi-grovel">)
 16: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE))
 17: ((:METHOD ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE :AROUND (T T)) ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "cffi-grovel">) [fast-method]
 18: (ASDF/OPERATE:LOAD-SYSTEM #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "cffi-grovel">)
 19: (ASDF/OPERATE:LOAD-SYSTEMS* (#<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "cffi-grovel">))
 20: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PARSE-DEFSYSTEM:REGISTER-SYSTEM-DEFINITION))
      [No Locals]
 21: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (ASDF/PARSE-DEFSYSTEM:DEFSYSTEM :STATIC-VECTORS :DESCRIPTION "Create vectors allocated in static memory." :AUTHOR "Stelian Ionescu <sionescu@cddr.org>" ...) #<NULL-LEXENV..
 22: (EVAL-TLF (ASDF/PARSE-DEFSYSTEM:DEFSYSTEM :STATIC-VECTORS :DESCRIPTION "Create vectors allocated in static memory." :AUTHOR "Stelian Ionescu <sionescu@cddr.org>" ...) 1 #<NULL-LEXENV>)
 23: ((FLET SB-FASL::EVAL-FORM :IN SB-INT:LOAD-AS-SOURCE) (ASDF/PARSE-DEFSYSTEM:DEFSYSTEM :STATIC-VECTORS :DESCRIPTION "Create vectors allocated in static memory." :AUTHOR "Stelian Ionescu <sionescu@cddr.o..
 24: (SB-INT:LOAD-AS-SOURCE #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /home/kite/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/static-vectors-1.6/static-vectors.asd" {BD8E701}> :VERBOSE NIL :PRINT NIL :CONTEXT "loading")
 25: ((FLET SB-FASL::LOAD-STREAM :IN LOAD) #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /home/kite/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/static-vectors-1.6/static-vectors.asd" {BD8E701}> NIL)
 26: (LOAD #P"/home/kite/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/static-vectors-1.6/static-vectors.asd" :VERBOSE NIL :PRINT NIL :IF-DOES-NOT-EXIST T :EXTERNAL-FORMAT :UTF-8)
 27: (UIOP/UTILITY:CALL-WITH-MUFFLED-CONDITIONS #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN UIOP/LISP-BUILD:LOAD*) {BD8A8D5}> ("Overwriting already existing readtable ~S." #(#:FINALIZERS-OFF-WARNING :ASDF-FINALIZERS)))
 28: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/FIND-SYSTEM:LOAD-ASD))
 29: (SB-IMPL::%WITH-STANDARD-IO-SYNTAX #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/FIND-SYSTEM:LOAD-ASD) {BD8A805}>)
 30: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/SYSTEM:FIND-SYSTEM))
 31: (ASDF/CACHE:CONSULT-ASDF-CACHE (ASDF/SYSTEM:FIND-SYSTEM "static-vectors") #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/SYSTEM:FIND-SYSTEM) {BD79A05}>)
 32: ((:METHOD ASDF/SYSTEM:FIND-SYSTEM (STRING)) "static-vectors" NIL) [fast-method]
 33: ((:METHOD ASDF/FIND-COMPONENT:FIND-COMPONENT (STRING T)) "static-vectors" NIL) [fast-method]
 34: (ASDF/FIND-COMPONENT:RESOLVE-DEPENDENCY-NAME #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "fast-io"> :STATIC-VECTORS NIL)
 35: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "fast-io"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PLAN::C) :IN ASDF/PLAN:TR..
 36: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 37: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "fast-io"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBD..
 38: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "fast-io" "package"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PL..
 39: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 40: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "fast-io" "pac..
 41: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "fast-io" "package"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PLAN:..
 42: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 43: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "fast-io" "packag..
 44: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "fast-io"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PLAN::C) :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVE..
 45: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 46: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "fast-io"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA N..
 47: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "jonathan"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PLAN::C) :IN ASDF/PLAN:T..
 48: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 49: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "jonathan"> #<CLOSURE (LAMB..
 50: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/COMPONENT:MODULE "jonathan" "src"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PLAN::C) :IN AS..
 51: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 52: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/COMPONENT:MODULE "jonathan" "src"> #<CLOS..
 53: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "jonathan" "src" "jonathan"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O..
 54: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 55: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "jonathan" "sr..
 56: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "jonathan" "src" "jonathan"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O AS..
 57: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 58: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "jonathan" "src" ..
 59: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/COMPONENT:MODULE "jonathan" "src"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PLAN::C) :IN ASDF/..
 60: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
      [No Locals]
 61: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/COMPONENT:MODULE "jonathan" "src"> #<CLOSURE..
 62: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "jonathan"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PLAN::C) :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAV..
 63: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 64: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "jonathan"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA ..
 65: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "http-body"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PLAN::C) :IN ASDF/PLAN:..
 66: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 67: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "http-body"> #<CLOSURE (LAM..
 68: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/COMPONENT:MODULE "http-body" "src"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PLAN::C) :IN A..
 69: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 70: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/COMPONENT:MODULE "http-body" "src"> #<CLO..
 71: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "http-body" "src" "http-body"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN:..
 72: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 73: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "http-body" "s..
 74: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "http-body" "src" "http-body"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ..
 75: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 76: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "http-body" "src"..
 77: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/COMPONENT:MODULE "http-body" "src"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PLAN::C) :IN ASDF..
 78: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 79: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/COMPONENT:MODULE "http-body" "src"> #<CLOSUR..
 80: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "http-body"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PLAN::C) :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRA..
 81: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 82: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "http-body"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA..
 83: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "clack-test"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PLAN::C) :IN ASDF/PLAN..
 84: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 85: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "clack-test"> #<CLOSURE (LA..
 86: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "clack-test" "src/test"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASD..
 87: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 88: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "clack-test" "..
 89: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "clack-test" "src/test"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/P..
 90: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 91: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "clack-test" "src..
 92: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "clack-test"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PLAN::C) :IN ASDF/PLAN:TR..
 93: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 94: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "clack-test"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBD..
 95: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "clack-v1-compat"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PLAN::C) :IN ASDF..
 96: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 97: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "clack-v1-compat"> #<CLOSUR..
 98: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/COMPONENT:MODULE "clack-v1-compat" "v1-compat/src/core"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::..
 99: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 100: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/COMPONENT:MODULE "clack-v1-compat" "v1-co..
 101: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "clack-v1-compat" "v1-compat/src/core" "builder"> #<CLOSURE ..
 102: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 103: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "clack-v1-comp..
 104: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "clack-v1-compat" "v1-compat/src/core" "builder"> #<CLOSURE (LA..
 105: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 106: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "clack-v1-compat"..
 107: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/COMPONENT:MODULE "clack-v1-compat" "v1-compat/src/core"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O A..
 108: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 109: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/COMPONENT:MODULE "clack-v1-compat" "v1-compa..
 110: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "clack-v1-compat"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PLAN::C) :IN ASDF/PL..
 111: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 112: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "clack-v1-compat"> #<CLOSURE (..
 113: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "caveman"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PLAN::C) :IN ASDF/PLAN:TR..
 114: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 115: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "caveman"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBD..
 116: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/COMPONENT:MODULE "caveman" "v1/src"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PLAN::C) :IN ..
 117: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 118: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/COMPONENT:MODULE "caveman" "v1/src"> #<CL..
 119: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/COMPONENT:MODULE "caveman" "v1/src" "core"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PLAN::..
 120: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 121: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/COMPONENT:MODULE "caveman" "v1/src" "core..
 122: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "caveman" "v1/src" "core" "caveman"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF..
 123: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 124: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:PREPARE-OP > #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "caveman" "v1/..
 125: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP :VERBOSE NIL> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "caveman" "v1/src" "core" "caveman"> #<CLOSURE (LAM..
 126: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 127: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP :VERBOSE NIL> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "cave..
 128: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP :VERBOSE NIL> #<ASDF/COMPONENT:MODULE "caveman" "v1/src" "core"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O AS..
 129: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 130: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP :VERBOSE NIL> #<ASDF/COMPONENT:MODULE "caveman" "v1/s..
 131: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP :VERBOSE NIL> #<ASDF/COMPONENT:MODULE "caveman" "v1/src"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PLAN..
 132: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 133: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP :VERBOSE NIL> #<ASDF/COMPONENT:MODULE "caveman" "v1/s..
 134: (ASDF/PLAN:MAP-DIRECT-DEPENDENCIES #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP :VERBOSE NIL> #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "caveman"> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (ASDF/PLAN::O ASDF/PLAN::C) :IN ASD..
 135: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/PLAN:TRAVERSE-ACTION))
 136: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION (ASDF/PLAN:PLAN-TRAVERSAL T T T)) #<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {B19FAE9}> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP :VERBOSE NIL> #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "caveman"> #<CLOSU..
 137: ((:METHOD ASDF/PLAN:MAKE-PLAN (T ASDF/OPERATION:OPERATION ASDF/COMPONENT:COMPONENT)) NIL #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP :VERBOSE NIL> #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "caveman"> :VERBOSE NIL) [fast-method]
 138: ((:METHOD ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE (ASDF/OPERATION:OPERATION ASDF/COMPONENT:COMPONENT)) #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP :VERBOSE NIL> #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "caveman"> :VERBOSE NIL) [fast-method]
 139: ((SB-PCL::EMF ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE) #<unused argument> #<unused argument> #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP :VERBOSE NIL> #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "caveman"> :VERBOSE NIL)
 140: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE))
      [No Locals]
 141: ((:METHOD ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE :AROUND (T T)) #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP :VERBOSE NIL> #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "caveman"> :VERBOSE NIL) [fast-method]
 142: ((SB-PCL::EMF ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE) #<unused argument> #<unused argument> ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP "caveman" :VERBOSE NIL)
 143: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE))
 144: (ASDF/CACHE:CALL-WITH-ASDF-CACHE #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE) {B1936FD}> :OVERRIDE NIL :KEY NIL)
 145: ((:METHOD ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE :AROUND (T T)) ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP "caveman" :VERBOSE NIL) [fast-method]
 146: ((:METHOD ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE :AROUND (T T)) ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP "caveman" :VERBOSE NIL) [fast-method]
 147: (ASDF/OPERATE:LOAD-SYSTEM "caveman" :VERBOSE NIL)
 148: (QUICKLISP-CLIENT::CALL-WITH-MACROEXPAND-PROGRESS #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN QUICKLISP-CLIENT::APPLY-LOAD-STRATEGY) {B0D55F5}>)
 149: (QUICKLISP-CLIENT::AUTOLOAD-SYSTEM-AND-DEPENDENCIES "caveman" :PROMPT NIL)
 150: ((:METHOD QL-IMPL-UTIL::%CALL-WITH-QUIET-COMPILATION (T T)) #<unavailable argument> #<CLOSURE (FLET QUICKLISP-CLIENT::QL :IN QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD) {C8944FD}>) [fast-method]
 151: ((:METHOD QL-IMPL-UTIL::%CALL-WITH-QUIET-COMPILATION :AROUND (QL-IMPL:SBCL T)) #<QL-IMPL:SBCL {CEFC949}> #<CLOSURE (FLET QUICKLISP-CLIENT::QL :IN QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD) {C8944FD}>) [fast-method]
 152: ((:METHOD QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD (T)) #<unavailable argument> :PROMPT NIL :SILENT NIL :VERBOSE NIL) [fast-method]
 153: (QL-DIST::CALL-WITH-CONSISTENT-DISTS #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD) {C88C625}>)
 154: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD :CAVEMAN) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
 155: (EVAL (QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD :CAVEMAN))
 156: (SWANK::EVAL-REGION "(ql:quickload :caveman) ..)
 157: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL))
 158: (SWANK-REPL::TRACK-PACKAGE #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL) {C80A12D}>)
 159: (SWANK::CALL-WITH-RETRY-RESTART "Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request." #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL) {C80A0CD}>)
 160: (SWANK::CALL-WITH-BUFFER-SYNTAX NIL #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL) {C80A0BD}>)
 161: (SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL "(ql:quickload :caveman) ..)
 162: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (SWANK-REPL:LISTENER-EVAL "(ql:quickload :caveman) ..)
 163: (EVAL (SWANK-REPL:LISTENER-EVAL "(ql:quickload :caveman) ..)
 164: (SWANK:EVAL-FOR-EMACS (SWANK-REPL:LISTENER-EVAL "(ql:quickload :caveman) ..)
 165: (SWANK::PROCESS-REQUESTS NIL)
 166: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS))
 167: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS))
 168: (SWANK/SBCL::CALL-WITH-BREAK-HOOK #<FUNCTION SWANK:SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS) {C4B607D}>)
 169: ((FLET SWANK/BACKEND:CALL-WITH-DEBUGGER-HOOK :IN "/home/kite/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/slime-v2.18/swank/sbcl.lisp") #<FUNCTION SWANK:SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::HAN..
 170: (SWANK::CALL-WITH-BINDINGS ((*STANDARD-INPUT* . #1=#<SWANK/GRAY::SLIME-INPUT-STREAM {C43DBB9}>) (*STANDARD-OUTPUT* . #2=#<SWANK/GRAY::SLIME-OUTPUT-STREAM {C4A98D1}>) (*TRACE-OUTPUT* . #2#) (*ERROR-OUT..
 171: (SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS #<SWANK::MULTITHREADED-CONNECTION {BBE2789}> NIL)
 172: ((FLET #:WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-1195 :IN SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE))
 173: ((FLET SB-THREAD::WITH-MUTEX-THUNK :IN SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE))
 174: ((FLET #:WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-647 :IN SB-THREAD::CALL-WITH-MUTEX))
 175: (SB-THREAD::CALL-WITH-MUTEX #<CLOSURE (FLET SB-THREAD::WITH-MUTEX-THUNK :IN SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE) {A527310D}> #<SB-THREAD:MUTEX "thread result lock" owner: #<SB-THREAD:THREAD ..
 176: (SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "repl-thread" RUNNING {C4B2519}> #S(SB-THREAD:SEMAPHORE :NAME "Thread setup semaphore" :%COUNT 0 :WAITCOUNT 0 :MUTEX #<SB-THREAD:MUTEX..
 177: ("foreign function: call_into_lisp")
 178: ("foreign function: funcall0")
 179: ("foreign function: new_thread_trampoline")
 180: ("foreign function: #xB7F9CF72")
      [No Locals]
```

... and the error:

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload :caveman)
To load "caveman":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    caveman
; Loading "caveman"
................

; file: /home/kite/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.17.1/toolchain/asdf-compat.lisp
; in: DEFUN BUNDLE-PATHNAME-TYPE
;     ((UIOP/OS:OS-UNIX-P) "o")
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   illegal function call

;     ((UIOP/OS:OS-WINDOWS-P)
;      (IF (UIOP/OS:FEATUREP '(:OR :MINGW32 :MINGW64))
;          "o"
;          "obj"))
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   illegal function call

;     ((UIOP/OS:OS-UNIX-P) "a")
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   illegal function call

;     ((UIOP/OS:OS-WINDOWS-P)
;      (IF (UIOP/OS:FEATUREP '(:OR :MINGW32 :MINGW64))
;          "a"
;          "lib"))
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   illegal function call

;     ((UIOP/OS:OS-MACOSX-P) "dylib")
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   illegal function call

;     ((UIOP/OS:OS-UNIX-P) "so")
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   illegal function call

;     ((UIOP/OS:OS-WINDOWS-P) "dll")
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   illegal function call

;     ((UIOP/OS:OS-UNIX-P) NIL)
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   illegal function call

;     ((UIOP/OS:OS-WINDOWS-P) "exe")
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   illegal function call
..
```

Already solved, by @cybevnm, in the comments ...

Comment: Try to load (ql:quickload :static-vectors), and see what happens

Comment: Tried that, even tried (ql:quickload :vecto).  Not much luck, still same error,

Comment: could you add the complete stacktrace, and the slime error

Comment: What does `(lisp-implementation-version)` return?

Comment: @coredump returns 1.3.9

Comment: :vecto has nothing to do with :static-vectors. Try to do your :static-vectors loading experiment using clean lisp instance, i.e. launch fresh emacs, launch fresh slime, and (ql:quickload :static-vectors) right away and see what happens.

Comment: There are hits on google for "caught ERROR: illegal function call (UIOP/OS:OS-WINDOWS-P)" - looks like the problem is with the obsolete ASDF version, which bundled with SBCL. Your (lisp-implementation-version) returns 1.3.9 which is quite fresh version - did you build your SBCL from sources ? Maybe there are some problems with your build ?

Comment: What does (asdf:asdf-version) return ?

Comment: Since first posting tge question, I have made several changes, for instance, (lisp-implementatiin-version) now returns 1.2.7 and (asdf:asdf-version) returns 3.1.3

Comment: Ok, looks like you need ASDF 3.1.5 at least. To get more recent ASDF you might build SBCL from source. Just download the archive from sbcl.org and follow instructions in the INSTALL file (something like "sh make.sh --fancy --prefix /opt/sbcl-new && sh install.sh"). Don't forget to tell SLIME to use the new SBCL - (setq inferior-lisp-program "/opt/sbcl-new/bin/sbcl") somewhere in emacs configuration.

Comment: Wow!! Worked like a charm, thanks a million,

Answer (score 3):

Loads fine on my Ubuntu 16.04 + SBCL 1.3.9.

Probably you have the problems due to the outdated quicklisp distribution.
Try `(ql:update-client)` and `(ql:update-all-dists)` to get an update.

[Quicklisp documentation](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/)

*Edit after discussion in comments:*

At least ASDF 3.1.5 is required for static-vectors (actually for cffi which is indirect dependency). SBCL 1.2.7 bundled with ASDF 3.1.3, so SBCL update is required in your case.

Probably related cffi pull request: https://github.com/cffi/cffi/pull/92

Comment: Tried the above, and told that my installations are the latest,

Comment: Will attempt to set up on an Ubuntu 16 environment,

Comment: It's good idea to give more details on error, particularly the stacktrace as @anquegi hinted in question comments. There should be something that causes the "READ error during COMPILE-FILE".

Comment: The screen with the error message contains it ("backtrace"). The point is to try to understand exact point (file, line) where the error occurs - you may browse/explore that screen, maybe that will give you idea what's going on...

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem on Debian 8 stable. The solution to it was to install the testing cl-asdf with APT. Alternatively you could just use the Quicklisp version too.

Thanks to #lisp on freenode for pointing me to it (https://github.com/cffi/cffi/pull/92).